# Formatting column text style of an ultragrid

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

Is there any way that it's possible to set the cell text style of an `UltraGrid` column? I have an `UltraGrid` with a column that has data which should not be displayed, but the column is needed in the grid. I want the characters in the column cells to be **** for example, or even `PasswordChar` style. I read that I need the `UltraTextEditor.dll` for this, however, I cannot find this file in the Infragistics folder on the server.

Any other ways it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

There is no PasswordChar property on the grid itself, but this can be done by using an UltraTextEditor control and attaching it to the grid.
Place an UltraTextEditor onto the form with the grid. Set the PasswordChar property of the UltraTextEditor to asterisk (*). In the InitializeLayout event of the grid, set the EditorControl property of the appropriate column to the UltraTextEditor control.
Note that there is no such library as UltraTextEditor.dll. UltraTextEditor is part of Infragistics.Win, so you can find it in Infragistics.Win.dll.

Comment: I've imported `Infragstics.Win.v5.1.dll` as well as 'Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.v5.1.dll` and neither of these seem to have added the `UltraTextEditor` to the toolbox?

Comment: You should have it. Instead of adding it trough designer try to add it run time like this                                                                                                 var ultraTextEditorPasswordEditor = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinEditors.UltraTextEditor();